# How to loop through table and update multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

hi base on the table below i have 2 table where name is sell record history and another is sell info..base on the sell info table josh have sold 100 how can i update to sell record history table

scenario:

josh package one already sold 50 how can add it up the 100 in sell info to 
package 1 50 add on to sold because the max cap is 100 and the balance of the sold add to package 2 of josh

```html
table - sell Record history  
name package max cap sold
Josh 1 100 0
Jack 1 100 0
Josh 2 100 0
Austin 1 100 0

table -sell info 
name sold
Josh 150
Jack 0
Austin 0
```

expected output will be :

```
name    |package|max cap    |sold
Josh    |1      |100        |100
Jack    |1      |100        |0
Josh    |2      |100        |50
Austin  |1      |100        |0
```

Comment: Hey Austin, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your question is very unclear, and it's tough to determine exactly what you want. Perhaps you can try to clarify, or even better, edit your question to show what the tables should look like *after* the query.

Comment: Total `sold`in `[sell Record history]` will not matches `sold` in `[sell info]`  ?

Comment: both will match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to do it in one simple query. The query below i uses recursive CTE.

Assumption : package is numeric and starts from 1 and increment by 1 without gap

```
-- Create sample table
declare @sell_record table
(
    name        varchar(6),
    package     int,
    max_cap     int,
    sold        int
)

declare @sell_info table
(
    name        varchar(6),
    sold        int
)

-- Insert sample data
insert into @sell_record select 'Josh', 1, 100, 0
insert into @sell_record select 'Jack', 1, 100, 0
insert into @sell_record select 'Josh', 2, 100, 0
insert into @sell_record select 'Austin', 1, 100, 0

insert into @sell_info select 'Josh', 150
insert into @sell_info select 'Jack', 0
insert into @sell_info select 'Austin', 0

-- The query. rcte is recursive cte
; with rcte as
(
    -- anchor member. Starts with package 1
    select  i.name, r.package,
            -- allocation of sold_qty to package
            alloc    = case when i.sold >= r.max_cap - r.sold 
                            then r.max_cap - r.sold 
                            else i.sold
                            end,
            -- balance of the sold qty after allocated
            bal_sold = case when i.sold >= r.max_cap - r.sold 
                            then i.sold - r.max_cap - r.sold 
                            else 0
                            end
    from    @sell_info i
            inner join @sell_record r   on  i.name  = r.name 
    where   r.package   = 1

    union all

    -- recursive member
    select  c.name, r.package,
            -- allocation of sold_qty to package
            alloc   = case  when c.bal_sold >= r.max_cap - r.sold 
                            then r.max_cap - r.sold 
                            else c.bal_sold
                            end,
            -- balance of the sold qty after allocated
            bal_sold = case when c.bal_sold >= r.max_cap - r.sold 
                            then c.bal_sold - r.max_cap - r.sold 
                            else 0
                            end
    from    rcte c
            inner join @sell_record r   on  c.name      = r.name 
                                        and c.package   = r.package - 1
)
-- Update back sell_record
update  r
set    sold = c.alloc
from    rcte c
        inner join @sell_record r   on  c.name  = r.name
                                    and c.package   = r.package

-- show the result
select  *
from    @sell_record

/*
name    package max_cap sold
Josh    1   100 100
Jack    1   100 0
Josh    2   100 50
Austin  1   100 0
*/
```